# Function that returns specified values, from an array of objects, if a property is true

Tags: javascript, function, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

Im working on a challenge: Given an array of objects, write a function admin that returns the name and birthdate of all users that are marked as "admin".

```
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Homer', 
    role: 'clerk', 
    dob: '12/02/1988',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lisa', 
    role: 'staff', 
    dob: '01/30/1965',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Marge', 
    role: 'associate', 
    dob: '09/10/1980',
    admin: true 
  }
]

function admin(myObj) {
  function groupBy(myObj, prop) {
  return myObj.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    let key = obj[prop]
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }
    acc[key].push(obj)
    return acc
    }, {});
  }
  let trueAdmin = groupBy(myObj, 'admin');
  console.log(trueAdmin[true].map(({name, dob}) => `Name: ${name}
Dob: ${dob}
`).join(`
`));
}

admin(users);
```

When I run tests, it comes back as undefined and i do not know why.  Im looking for an expected output:
admin(users)

```
// Name: Marge 
// Dob: 09/10/1980
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to log them to the console you can simply use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Homer', 
    role: 'clerk', 
    dob: '12/02/1988',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lisa', 
    role: 'staff', 
    dob: '01/30/1965',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Marge', 
    role: 'associate', 
    dob: '09/10/1980',
    admin: true 
  }
]

function admin(myArray) {
  myArray.forEach(user => {
    if (user.admin) console.log(`Name: ${user.name}, DOB: ${user.dob}`);
  });
}

admin(users);
```

---

If you want to return the matched users you can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return an array filtered by a callback, and then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that to alter the elements of the filtered array so they conform to the expected output.

In the following snippet `admin()` returns an array of mutated `user` objects with only `name` and `dob` keys.

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Homer', 
    role: 'clerk', 
    dob: '12/02/1988',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lisa', 
    role: 'staff', 
    dob: '01/30/1965',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Marge', 
    role: 'associate', 
    dob: '09/10/1980',
    admin: true 
  }
]

function admin(myArray) {
  return myArray.filter(u => u.admin).map(u => ({name: u.name, dob: u.dob}));
}

console.log(admin(users));
```

`filter(u => u.admin)` iterates over each object and returns an array containing elements for which `user.admin` is `true`.

`map(u => ({name: u.name, dob: u.dob}))` then iterates over each element of the filtered array and changes each one to be an object containing just `name:` and `dob:` of the passed object.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the difference between simply printing properties to the screen and getting the array.map technique to actually return the desired properties.  I've only been coding a few weeks now and it is cool to see the variety of built in functions that can display the data in different ways.  I appreciate your feedback and guidance.